# Proving that in $\Bbb R^4$ there is an infinite sequence of linearly independent two-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anybody knows how to prove that in $\Bbb R^4$ there is an infinite sequence of two-dimensional subspaces $W_1,W_2,\dots$ such that for every $i\ne j$ $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$?

Comment: Can you do this in $\mathbb R^2$ for one dimensional subspaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $W_i=\langle(1,0,i,0), (0,1,0,i)\rangle$. An arbitrary vector in $W_i$ looks like $(a,b,ai,bi)$ and an arbitrary one in $W_j$ is $(c,d,cj,dj)$. It's not difficult to see that the only intersection is when $a=b=c=d=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Define a sequence of $4×2$ matrices $A_n$ with $n\ge1$ as follows:
$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_{n+1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&0&-\sin\theta&0\\
0&\cos\psi&0&-\sin\psi\\
\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta&0\\
0&\sin\psi&0&\cos\psi\end{bmatrix}A_n$$
where $\theta$ and $\psi$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$. $W_n$ is then the column space of $A_n$, and $\{W_n\}$ has the required properties.